# Looking for a proper word to express lack of self-control

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Need a proper adjective that can be used to call a trait when a person consciously lacks self-control/discipline while trying avoid certain things.

A simple example could be a person trying to wake up early in the morning but never considers it being important knowing the benefits of such a trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose the common vernacular "Slacker".  One who "slacks" takes a non-committal and uninvolved procrastination, or denial of responsibility to the level that it is perceived as a personality flaw.

Not to be confused with "Lazy", a "Slacker" is able to improve, but prefers the conscious choice of 'Slack'.  Additionally, 'Slack' sometimes requires more effort than acceptance of responsibility.

Example:  "He often spent more time slacking, dodging bill collectors and fabricating excuses than he would have spent working at a decent job..."

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!